# Java Serversocket not accepting connection

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

So I'm making a program involving client/server connections and I was having trouble getting them to work. In order to try and isolate the problem, I made two test programs to try and get a connection:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
     System.out.println("here");
     Socket s = new Socket(IP, PORT);
     System.out.println("sent");
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
     System.out.println("Client Error");
  }

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
     ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(8921);
     Socket a = s.accept();
     System.out.println("accepted");
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
     System.out.println("Server Error");
  }

}
```

The port value is one I chose randomly, so if there's a better way to choose one please let me know. The IP address is the IPv4 address for the machine. I run these programs on separate computers and neither prints accepted or sent. However, neither of the error messages are printed either, which leads to believe that there is some problem while accepting? Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Your program cannot terminate without printing one message or the other.

Comment: Sorry, after a while the client program will 'give up' and print the error.

Comment: Your code works for me. Perhaps you have a firewall on the computer running the server that blocks incoming connections.

Comment: Yea, I thought it might have something to do with the firewall. Do you know any more information about how to possibly fix it?

Comment: That would be very specific to your computer, OS, etc. Your best bet is to google for the answer.

Comment: When you get an exception, print the exception. Not some random message of your own devising. It contains no useful information except that an error happened. You've thrown all the useful information away. When debugging, print the stack trace. It will tell you all you need, in most cases.

Comment: If you called `e.printStackTrace()` then *the computer would tell you what went wrong*...

Answer (score -1):

It's not printing anything because s.accept() "Listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it." - the JavaDoc

It must be still listening, therefor your code is un-reachable.